# Выполнять каждые 30 дней

Tags: php

Нужно сделать запуск скрипта каждые 30 дней (или каждый месяц) от определенной даты. Даты берутся из бд, их много и они разные.

Допустим у нас есть дата: 10.01.19, нужно что-бы скрипт срабатывал через каждые 30 дней. Т.е. 09.02.19, 11.03.19, 10.03.19 и т.д.

Придумал только это:

```
$now = time();
$save_date = strtotime($update_date);
$date_diff = $now - $save_date;
$datefloor = floor($date_diff / (60 * 60 * 24));
if($datefloor >= 30){
  echo 'ok';
}
```

Но так скрипт будет выполнятся только 1 раз, т.е. совсем не то что нужно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-то варианты реализации.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону CRON

Comment: @u_mulder Забыл написать что даты будут разные. Крон можно настроить на запуск каждые 30 дней, но не от определенной даты. Т.е. скрипт будет запускаться каждые 30 дней в один и тот же день. Такой вариант не подходит.

Comment: @g4343, а может быть стоит попробовать в скрипте, который вызывается CRON, удалить текущую задачу и установить новую с нужным временем?

Comment: Ну так запустите крон на каждый день и проверяйте не прошло ли 30 дней с какого-то момента.

Comment: Записывать куда-то не текущую дату, а следующую дату. Запускать по крону каждый день. Если сегодня не та дата - прекращаем работу. Если дата совпала - выполнить действия и записать следующую дату.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой вариант функции (вместо вашей), которая делает то, что вы пытались реализовать.

Она по параметрам `определенная дата из бд`, `интервал` и `текущая дата` определяет - пора или нет запускать некую обработку:

```
<?php

/**
 * Делятся ли без остатка кол-во дней в периоде на количество дней интервала
 *
 * @param $start DateTime начало периода
 * @param $days int интервал, в днях
 * @param $now DateTime конец периода
 * @return boolean
 */
function isDue(DateTime $start, $days = 30, DateTime $now = null)
{
    $now = $now === null? new DateTime("now"): $now;
    return $now->diff($start)->format("%a") % $days === 0;
}
```

Вот примеры ее использования:

```
/
// тесты
//
echo (int)isDue(
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "10.01.19"),
    30,
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "08.02.19")
); // --> 0

echo (int)isDue(
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "10.01.19"),
    30,
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "09.02.19")
); // --> 1

echo (int)isDue(
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "10.01.19"),
    30,
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "10.03.19")
); // --> 0

echo (int)isDue(
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "10.01.19"),
    30,
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "11.03.19")
); // --> 1

echo (int)isDue(
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "10.01.19"),
    30,
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "09.04.19")
); // --> 0

echo (int)isDue(
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "10.01.19"),
    30,
    DateTime::createFromFormat("d.m.y", "10.04.19")
); // --> 1
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31c3a2e1382f14c336d043afdf6afacbc3151d32)